# R function to search for a function

Tags: r, matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Update:
The original question is: Is there an R function using the same algorithm implemented in the "lsqnonlin" function in matlab? However, the answer is more related to searching a function in R. I think the answer is in general very helpful for R users. So I edited the title but asked the original question again here: [In R, how to do nonlinear least square optimization which involves solving differential equations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687326/implementation-of-trust-region-reflective-optimization-algorithm-in-r)

I am doing nonlinear least-square optimizations and found that the matlab function `lsqnonlin` performs better than all the optimization algorithms I tried in R (including the algorithms in function `optimx`, `nlm`, `nlminb`, `solnp`, etc.) in the sense that it is faster and found the "more correct" solution.

However, I did not find an implementation of the 'trust-region-reflective' algorithm in R that is used in Matlab. Does someone know if there is already an implementation? Also, is it always true that the 'trust-region-reflective' algorithm is a better algorithm for this kind of optimization?

Comment: It is  better to ask this question here :http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks, @agstudy. I was actually not sure where to post. But I think I Matthew Plourde has answered my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like `lsqnonlin` in the `pracma` package is what you're looking for.

I recommend installing the `sos` package for R. Its purpose is to help you answer questions like 'Is there a function out there that does this?'. `findFn` in this package will search what's on CRAN for the term you supply.

```
library(sos)
findFn('lsqnonlin')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I knew neither `sos` nor `lsqnonlin` in `pracma`, I will try them out.

Comment: I started working on this problem again and found that the `lsqnonlin` in the `pracma` package only implemented the levenberg-Marquardt algorithm. Here is the description of the function "lsqnonlin solves nonlinear least-squares problems, including nonlinear data-fitting problems, through
the Levenberg-Marquardt approach.
lsqnonneg solve nonnegative least-squares constraints problem."